# What is the simplest way to SSO between Wordpress site on main domain and non wordpress site on sub domain

Tags: php, wordpress, session, single-sign-on, credentials

I have a website `www.mydomain.com` which is a **Wordpress website** and I installed another PHP script **(not Wordpress)** on `www.panel.mydomain.com`

I created one database for Wordpress and one for the PHP script on the **same host**

the PHP script on the sub domain is a full independent website which works on its own perfectly

on my Wordpress website I sell different package with **Woocommerce**, and after purchasing some packages the **credential and information of my current user on Wordpress** is getting duplicated on the **user table of my other PHP script**

I can do to this stage with no problem
and here is what I cant figure it out how to solve:

I want my users dont see the **login page** of my PHP script on subdomain at all and if the user on wordpress is logged in, the subdomain **automatically get logged in** and if the user is logged out 
**none of the urls on subdomains be accessible** and redirect to www.mydomain.com/login or whatever page for login

so **basically removing the second script login step**
Im kind of new to php

please give me some hints or some resources
I really have no clue after days of searching
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you send the user a security token (cookie) which they then have to use to be able to prove their identity on your other system.

When you log into WordPress, you will need to make a plugin that generates a random string that it sends to the user's browser and saves it in your user account on the PHP site.  Then when the user goes to your PHP site, it requests a cookie at the login page.  If the user is able to provide a cookie, the PHP site looks it up, and logs you in using the cookie in place of a username & password.

There are plenty of ways of hardening the security on this method to prevent the token from being stolen, but for most use cases, just transmitting it over HTTPS and making sure it is adequately long/complex should be enough.

Comment: so as I understand correctly first I should add a column on user table on my php script as a token and every time I log into wordpress I generate a code and write it into this user table
then when I enter every address on my subdomain like www.panel.mydomain/xxx I check if the token exist and if so I start a session for that user ??

main question is , how can I check when somebody enter this address www.panel.mydomain.com/xxx which user should be checked for token ??

Comment: second , if for any reason the user erase his history, cookie on the browser, there is still a token on the table!! and it will make a problem

third, is it the easiest way ?

Comment: I've come across to some answers, articles about JWT (Jason Web Tokens) which is a security string as you mentioned, do you have any in depth example of that in action ?

Comment: For www.panel.mydomain/xxx, you probably already have a security script that is called with an include or require for each page.  In a normal login situation, it's looking for a session variable to see if you are logged in and what your permissions level is and redirects you to login or 403 page if you are not logged in, you just need to add a condition to also look for a valid token so you don't have to manually add it to each page

Comment: As for the token still being there, the token normally has an expiration which you track with a separate datetime column in your user database.  So when you check for the token, you also check if it was made in the last 24-hr or whatever your limit is.  Also, most browsers clear cookies after 2 weeks so even if the token stays there in your database, the browser will lose track of it after so long.

Comment: JSON web tokens are the most common method for handling the tokens you send to the client, but you still need to keep track of it on your side of things to verify who owns that token.  Lastly, if they clear their tokens in thier browser and it's still there on the table, it does not matter. They just need to log back into wordpress which will generate a new token and overwrite the old one in the table.